# Min/Max zoom levels for a TileLayer

Tags: openlayers

I create my openlayers map like this:

```
tmpLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.XYZ({
            url: my_tile_url,
            crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
        })
});
```

The webmap I want to include only supports zoom levels 8-15. I want the map to disappear when the current zoom is not within that range.

I could find an [example in the openlayers documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/min-max-resolution.html) where this is achieved with `min/maxResolution`. Is this also possible with specifying zoom levels?

To clarify, I do not want to constrain the zoom levels (like [here](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/zoom-constrained.html)), I want the map to disappear outside that range like in the above example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [openlayers documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.XYZ.html), `ol.source.XYZ` has a `minZoom` and `maxZoom` parameter. However these do not show the desired effect. They do limit the zoom level, to the specified range, however the tiles do not disappear when out of this range.

I found the following workaround, using the `change:resolution` event listener:

```
tmpLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        url: my_tile_url,
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
        minZoom: 8,
        maxZoom: 15
    })
});

map.getView().on('change:resolution', function() {
    layers = map.getLayers();
    layers.forEach(function(layer, i, a) {
        tmpSource = layer.getSource()
        // 'duck typing' for source object, vector layers don't have a zoom level.
        if(typeof tmpSource.getTileGrid === 'function') {
            if(map.getView().getZoom() > tmpSource.getTileGrid().maxZoom ||
                map.getView().getZoom() < tmpSource.getTileGrid().minZoom) {
                layer.setVisible(false);
            } else {
                layer.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As a more up-to-date answer, you can use the minResolution and maxResolution flags on the layer to achieve the desired effect, eg:

```
tmpLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    maxResolution: map.getView().getResolutionForZoom(source.minZoom),
    minResolution: map.getView().getResolutionForZoom(source.maxZoom+1),
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        url: my_tile_url,
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
        minZoom: 8,
        maxZoom: 15
    })
});
```

I'm using the View object for the map here as a convenience to avoid coding in the resolution numbers manually (they're an unpleasant calculation to make).

Note that this only works if your projection for the tile source is the same as the projection for your map. If it's different - you'll need to correctly set the resolution arguments appropriately (might be easiest to create a dummy `View` object with your tile source's projection and use that).