# Using GeoServer WMS min/max scale in OpenLayers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wms, tiles

I have some WMS published from a GeoServer and thanks to the SLD, I defined the min/max scales to bounds my WMS display.
The point is that in OpenLayers, I can't figure out how to use those scales neither how to setup the min/max scales to bounds my Tile layers.
I saw a lot of things a bit hacky (like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234039/min-max-zoom-levels-for-a-tilelayer)) with min/max resolutions but maybe I missed something simpler...

Comment: What's "hacky" in the solution proposed by tr00st in the question you are referring to?

Comment: Using the view object or creating a new one in a projection-blind way, all of that, just for creating a Tile object seems to be a bit overkill in my point of view... but maybe it's the right way to do so ! I just want to find kind of a good practice ! :)

Comment: Oh and furthermore, this solution is using the zoom level and not the scale value as I liked to do!

Comment: Ups, overlooked you are talking about scale, not zoom. Map scale is very tricky subject for browser maps, since it's dependent on actual screen DPI and browser zoom setting.

Comment: No problem ! :)
I'm a bit surprise because in a Desktop SIG there the same problematic but the scale seems to have a better handling...